# How do I resize an object in actionscript 3 without changing the hitbox?

Tags: actionscript-3, event-handling, resize

When I resize a button in actionscript 3 the hitbox changes to the text instead of the square in my assignment example:

http://www.datafilehost.com/download-5ff20e2c.html

Video Explaining Issue: http://sdrv.ms/YcnjYV

Here is the code:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

trace("Stage(X,Y):" + stage.stageWidth + "X" + stage.stageHeight);

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mousePosition);
clickMe.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, handleClicks); 
function mousePosition(event:MouseEvent) {

    if(clickMe.mouseX >= 0 && clickMe.mouseX <= clickMe.width && clickMe.mouseY >= 0 && clickMe.mouseY <= clickMe.height)
    {
        do
        {
            var newX = Math.floor(Math.random()*stage.stageWidth);
            var newY = Math.floor(Math.random()*stage.stageHeight)

        }while(newX >= stage.stageWidth - clickMe.width || newY >= stage.stageHeight - clickMe.height)

        clickMe.x = newX;
        clickMe.y = newY;

        if(clickMe.width > 50)
        {
            clickMe.width=clickMe.width - 5;
            clickMe.height = clickMe.width - 5;
        }
    }
}

function handleClicks(event:MouseEvent)
{
    trace("Button Clicked!");
}
```

How can I get the hitbox to stay the same when resizing an object?

Comment: if you make the text box a dynamic text field and name it say `txt` and then disable it in your code like `clickMe.txt.mouseEnabled = false` does this behavior still happen? What exactly is `clickMe`? Movieclip with a blue square and textfield?

Comment: oh you posted the FLA..nvm

Answer (score 1):

this seems like a better and cleaner approach to what you are doing (assuming you move the clickMe clip to a random position and shrink it by 5px)

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

clickMe.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, moveSquare);

function moveSquare(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    var newX       = Math.floor(Math.random()*stage.stageWidth);
    var newY       = Math.floor(Math.random()*stage.stageHeight);
    clickMe.x      = newX;
    clickMe.y      = newY;
    clickMe.width  = clickMe.width - 5;
    clickMe.height = clickMe.height - 5;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing of button size affects on mouseX/mouseY value inside it. So dont rely on it and just use checking based on button position and size.

```
if(mouseX >= clickMe.x && mouseX <= clickMe.x+clickMe.width && mouseY >= clickMe.y && mouseY <= clickMe.y+clickMe.height)
```

Comment: Ah so instead of relying on clickMe.mouseX which gets altered when changing the size, I use the the position of mouseX relative to the stage. I will try this!